# How to pass data from jquery to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, binding, nunjucks

Now I have a seperate script which uses jquery which calls data from an api

```
 function sendRequest() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3002/api/people",
            type: "get", //send it through get method
            data: { 
                filters
            },
            success: function(response) {

               console.log("Response :" , response)
              //Do Something    
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              //Do Something to handle error
            }
          });
    }
```

Now I have the html which is the script is being called on

```
 <div class="item col-lg-4 grid-group-item list-group-item mh-animate">
                              <div class="vehicle-wrap">
                                <div class="v-image">
                                  <div class="v-special"><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Special</div>
                                  <img class="group list-group-image img-fluid" src="" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="v-info">
                                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><a href=""> 2019 Ford F-150 XLT </a></h4>
                                  <div class="v-info-details">
                                    <div class="v-details">

                                      <ul>
                                        <li><strong>Body Style: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Model Code: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Engine: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Drive Type: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Transmission: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Ext. Color: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Int. Color: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>MPG: </strong>19&nbsp;City&nbsp;/&nbsp;25&nbsp;Hwy</li>
                                        <li class="vinDisplay"><strong>VIN #: </strong><span></span></li>
                                        <li><strong>Stock #: </strong></li>
                                        </li>
                                      </ul>

                                    </div>
```

I could Even log the data when the page is being loaded

```
https://imgur.com/a/EQzDsMv
```

Now How I am going to plot those data from the request to the html ? Do i need templating engine like Nunjucks to that ? cause I am use to angular and other Frameworks I am just new on using jquery . Any idea?

Comment: Using `.html()` or `.append()` will achieve your need.

Comment: can you post an examlpe sir ? based on html

Comment: > `cause I am use to angular and other Frameworks I am just new on using jquery`. It's a little bit strange. Imho, `jquery` is obsolete. Yes, it's possible to use `nunjucks`, but there is no way to data binding.

Comment: cause the app is all backend rendered only one page of the app which is requires SPA\

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you are asking how to edit HTML with jQuery.

If so, then you can use

```
$("#elementIdGoesHere").html(dataGoesHere)
```

if you are selecting by ID and

```
$(".elementClassGoesHere").html(dataGoesHere)
```

if you are selecting by class name.

Comment: can you post an example Sir , jsut barely new to jquery

Comment: Not editing  , I mean wanna to load the response to html

Comment: The code I provided will basically change the content of the HTML. So, let say the HTML is a HTML p tag and it has no content (nothing between the beginning and closing tags).

Then you write this code: $("p").html("Some random data..") If so, the p tag's content will change to the string therefore will display the words "Some random data.."

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var ajaxJsonData = [{
      name: 'a',
      value: 'value1'
    },
    {
      name: 'b',
      value: 'value2'
    },
    {
      name: 'c',
      value: 'value3'
    }
  ];

  //var temp = '';
  //for (var i = 0; i < ajaxJsonData.length; i++) {
  //temp += '<div>name: ' + ajaxJsonData[i].name + ',value: ' +      //ajaxJsonData[i].value + '</div>';
  //}

  var value = 'value';
  var $temp = `
  <div class="item col-lg-4 grid-group-item list-group-item mh-animate">
                              <div class="vehicle-wrap">
                                <div class="v-image">
                                  <div class="v-special"><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Special</div>
                                  <img class="group list-group-image img-fluid" src="" alt="" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="v-info">
                                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><a href=""> 2019 Ford F-150 XLT </a></h4>
                                  <div class="v-info-details">
                                    <div class="v-details">

                                      <ul>
                                        <li><strong>Body Style: ${value} </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Model Code: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Engine: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Drive Type: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Transmission: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Ext. Color: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>Int. Color: </strong></li>
                                        <li><strong>MPG: </strong>19&nbsp;City&nbsp;/&nbsp;25&nbsp;Hwy</li>
                                        <li class="vinDisplay"><strong>VIN #: </strong><span></span></li>
                                        <li><strong>Stock #: </strong></li>
                                        </li>
                                      </ul>

                                    </div>
  `

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.container').html($temp);
  }, 2000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"></div>
```

I simulated the ajax asynchronous request and then dynamically inserted the html fragment.

Comment: how about the data from the ajax response ? the json array of objects?

Comment: You can iterate through and finally stitch it into a string

Comment: I modified my answer. If it helps you, please accept my answer, thank you:) @Mr.MarkTawin

Comment: I have seen your point on the answer sir but what if i have tons of html element like in my example above do i need to do it one by one element in the temp

Comment: like each <li><strong>Body Style: </strong></li>

Comment: can you please based the html on the html i have given above on my question ?

Comment: You can try using the es6 `Template strings` syntax, so you don't have to splicing one by one, but this syntax is not supported on some browsers. You can view more compatibility information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Sir is this only the best option on doing this ? can we use template engine like nunjucks ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201480/discussion-between-mr-mark-tawin-and-sugars).